# Why parallel stream get collected sequentially in Java 8

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream

Why `forEach` prints numbers in random order, while `collect` always collects elements in original order, even from parallel stream?

```
Integer[] intArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
List<Integer> listOfIntegers = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(intArray));

System.out.println("Parallel Stream: ");
listOfIntegers
  .stream()
  .parallel()
  .forEach(e -> System.out.print(e + " "));
System.out.println();

// Collectors         
List<Integer> l = listOfIntegers
  .stream()
  .parallel()
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(l);
```

Output:

```
Parallel Stream: 
8 1 6 2 7 4 5 3 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

There are two different kinds of "ordering" going on here, which makes the discussion confusing.

One kind is *encounter order*, which is defined in the [streams documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Ordering). A good way to think about this is the *spatial* or *left-to-right* order of elements in the source collection. If the source is a `List`, consider the earlier elements being to the left of later elements.

There is also *processing* or *temporal* order, which isn't defined in the documentation, but which is the time order in which elements are processed by different threads. If the elements of a list are being processed in parallel by different threads, a thread might process the rightmost element in the list before the leftmost element. But the next time it might not.

Even when computations are done in parallel, most `Collectors` and some terminal operations are carefully arranged so that they preserve *encounter order* from the source through to the destination, independently of the *temporal order* in which different threads might process each element.

Note that the `forEach` terminal operation does **not** preserve encounter order. Instead, it's run by whatever thread happens to produce the next result. If you want something like `forEach` that preserves encounter order, use `forEachOrdered` instead.

See also the [Lambda FAQ](http://www.lambdafaq.org/in-what-order-do-the-elements-of-a-stream-become-available/) for further discussion about ordering issues.

Answer (score 15):

The [`Collectors.toList` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--) specifies that the returned `Collector` adds elements to the list in encounter order.

> Returns:
>
> a Collector which collects all the input elements into a List, in encounter order

It doesn't matter whether the `Stream` is parallel; the order is preserved.

Additionally, looking at the `Collectors` source code, the returned `Collector` calls `addAll` on an `ArrayList` when merging, and that preserves the order.  E.g. if one thread has {1, 2} and the next thread has {3, 4}, then the call to `addAll` yields {1, 2, 3, 4}.  Also, the returned `Collector` doesn't have the `UNORDERED` characteristic.

Comment: How can the order be known after `parallel` is invoked ?

Comment: What makes you think `parallel` would discard the order?

Comment: It would discard order once terminal operation reached. Not necessarily, depends on CPU and OS, but first example `forEach` proves that.

Comment: @rgettman Ok, seems I read JavaDoc not carefully, so toList always preserves original order and ignores "parallel" method. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @BaratSahdzijeu I don't think it ignores `parallel`, it just combines the results from the worker threads in order.  On the other hand, your `forEach` will print the elements in the worker threads themselves; that will destroy any order.

Comment: @BaratSahdzijeu It does not ignore `parallel`. In parallel operation, the *temporal* (time) order of the processing can and will vary among elements from run to run. But for sources and destinations like Lists, the "encounter" order (spatial, or left-to-right order) is preserved from the source through to the destination.

Comment: @rgettman Correct, `forEach` doesn't preserve encounter order. If preserving encounter order is necessary, use `forEachOrdered`.