# Is .collect guaranteed to be ordered on parallel streams?

Tags: java, list, java-8

Given I have a list of Strings `List<String> toProcess`. The results have to be in the order the original lines were given.
I want to utilize the new parallel streams.

Does the following code **guarantee** that the results will be in the same order they were in the original list?

```
// ["a", "b", "c"]
List<String> toProcess;

// should be ["a", "b", "c"]
List<String> results = toProcess.parallelStream()
                                .map(s -> s)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Yes, the order is guaranteed.

#### Stream.collect() API documentation

The starting place is to look at what determines whether a reduction is concurrent or not. [`Stream.collect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-)'s description says the following:

> If the stream is parallel, and the `Collector` is [concurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.Characteristics.html#CONCURRENT), and either the stream is unordered or the collector is [unordered](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.Characteristics.html#UNORDERED), then a concurrent reduction will be performed (see [`Collector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) for details on concurrent reduction.)

The first condition is satisfied: the stream is parallel. How about the second and third: is the `Collector` concurrent and unordered?

#### Collectors.toList() API documentation

[`toList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--)'s documentation reads:

> Returns a `Collector` that accumulates the input elements into a new `List`. There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the `List` returned; if more control over the returned `List` is required, use `toCollection(Supplier)`.
>
> Returns:
> a Collector which collects all the input elements into a List, **in encounter order**

An operation that works in [encounter order](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Ordering) operates on the elements in their original order. This overrides parallelness.

#### Implementation code

Inspecting the implementation of `Collectors.java` confirms that `toList()` does **not** include the `CONCURRENT` or `UNORDERED` traits.

```
public static <T>
Collector<T, ?, List<T>> toList() {
    return new CollectorImpl<>((Supplier<List<T>>) ArrayList::new, List::add,
                               (left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; },
                               CH_ID);
}

// ...

static final Set<Collector.Characteristics> CH_ID
        = Collections.unmodifiableSet(EnumSet.of(Collector.Characteristics.IDENTITY_FINISH));
```

Notice how the collector has the `CH_ID` trait set, which has only the single `IDENTITY_FINISH` trait. `CONCURRENT` and `UNORDERED` are not there, so the reduction cannot be concurrent.

A non-concurrent reduction means that, if the stream is parallel, collection can proceed in parallel, but it will be split into several thread-confined intermediate results which are then combined. This ensures the combined result is in encounter order.

**See also:** [Why parallel stream get collected sequentially in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29709140/why-parallel-stream-get-collected-sequentially-in-java-8/29713386#29713386)

Comment: Note that all this only counts if the stream is ordered to begin with.  If it is unordered, all bets are off, since it has no intrinsic encounter order.

Answer (score 7):

You are guaranteed to get the elements in encounter order.

From [documentation of `toList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--):

> Returns:
>          a Collector which collects all the input elements into a List, **in encounter order**

See [java.util.streams summary](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Ordering) for more information on the term "encounter order".

Furthermore, [`List#spliterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#spliterator--) documentation requires that the all implementations of `List` produce spliterators that are `ORDERED`:

> The Spliterator reports Spliterator.SIZED and Spliterator.ORDERED. Implementations should document the reporting of additional characteristic values.

Oddly enough, while `List` interface requires `iterator()` to produce elements in "proper sequence", `spliterator()` is only required to be ordered but not specifically required to follow the list's natural ordering.

So, to answer your question, the list produced by `toList` is guaranteed to contain the elements exactly as the **source list**'s spliterator orders them.  It does not matter whether the stream is parallel or sequential.