# Using CompletableFuture within Filter Function

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, completable-future

I have a use case in which I want to filter out few elements in the list based on a Network call that I perform on the element. To accomplish this I am using streams, filter and Completable Future. The goal is to do async execution so that the operation becomes efficient. The pseudo code for this is mentioned below.

```
public List<Integer> afterFilteringList(List<Integer> initialList){
   List<Integer> afterFilteringList =initialList.stream().filter(element -> {
        boolean valid = true;
        try{
            valid = makeNetworkCallAndCheck().get();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return valid;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());

    return afterFilteringList;
}
public CompletableFuture<Boolean> makeNetworkCallAndCheck(Integer value){
   return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(resultOfNetWorkCall(value);
 }
```

The question I am having over here is, Am I doing this operation in an Async way itself?(As I am using 'get' function within the filter will it block the execution and make it sequential only) Or Is there a better way of doing this in Async way using Completable Future and Filters in Java 8.

Comment: You forgot to pass `element` to `makeNetworkCallAndCheck`. Also, it looks weird that the exceptional case is considered “valid”.

Comment: @Holger The title mismatches the actual question I believe. *Am I doing this operation in an Async way itself?* ... IMHO the calls are not async and the gets would be blocking...thoughts?

Comment: @nullpointer well, calling `get()` immediately destroys the benefit of asynchronous execution, no doubt, but I don’t know, what to suggest as solution, given this code. E.g. the input `List<Integer>` magically becomes a `List<Long>` during the stream operation, to eventually be returned as `List<Integer>`. I guess, it’s supposed to be the same `Integer` objects all the time, but I don’t want to write code based on assumptions…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call `get` immediately, you are indeed destroying the benefit of asynchronous execution. The solution is to collect all asynchronous jobs first, before joining.

```
public List<Integer> afterFilteringList(List<Integer> initialList){
    Map<Integer,CompletableFuture<Boolean>> jobs = initialList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), this::makeNetworkCallAndCheck));
    return initialList.stream()
        .filter(element -> jobs.get(element).join())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
public CompletableFuture<Boolean> makeNetworkCallAndCheck(Integer value){
   return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> resultOfNetWorkCall(value));
}
```

Of course, the method `makeNetworkCallAndCheck` has to initiate a truly asynchronous operation as well. Calling a method synchronously and returning a `completedFuture` is not sufficient. I provided a simple exemplary asynchronous operation here, but for I/O operations, you likely want to provide your own `Executor`, tailored to the number of simultaneous connections you want to allow.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `get()`, it will not be Async

`get()`: *Waits if necessary for this future to complete, and then returns its result.*

If you want to process all the request in Async. You can use `CompletetableFuture.allOf()`

```
public List<Integer> filterList(List<Integer> initialList){
    List<Integer> filteredList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
    AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(0);
    CompletableFuture[] completableFutures = new CompletableFuture[initialList.size()];
    initialList.forEach(x->{
        completableFutures[atomicInteger.getAndIncrement()] = CompletableFuture
            .runAsync(()->{
                if(makeNetworkCallAndCheck(x)){
                    filteredList.add(x);
                }
        });
    });

    CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFutures).join();
    return filteredList;
}

private Boolean makeNetworkCallAndCheck(Integer value){
    // TODO: write the logic;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: There is no guaranty that the result list has the right order with this code.

Comment: You don't need an `AtomicInteger` here, because it is not being shared with another thread.

Answer (score 0):

`Collection.parallelStream()` is an easy way to do the async stuff for a collection. You can modify your code as the following:

```
public List<Integer> afterFilteringList(List<Integer> initialList){
    List<Integer> afterFilteringList =initialList
            .parallelStream()
            .filter(this::makeNetworkCallAndCheck)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return afterFilteringList;
}
public Boolean makeNetworkCallAndCheck(Integer value){
    return resultOfNetWorkCall(value);
}
```

You can customize your own executor by [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22269778/5053214). And the result order is guaranteed according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29711206/5053214).

I have write the following code to verify my what I said.

```
public class  DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(50);
        final List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            integers.add(i);
        }
        long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<Integer> items = forkJoinPool.submit(() ->
                integers
                        .parallelStream()
                        .filter(it -> {
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(10000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            return true;
                        })
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .get();
        long after = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(after - before);
    }
}
```

I create my own `ForkJoinPool`, and it takes me 10019 milliseconds to finish 50 jobs in parallel although each one costs 10000 milliseconds.

Comment: The disadvantage of parallel streams is the lack of control over the executor, as for I/O operations, you usually don’t want the default pool parallelism, which is tailored to the number of CPU cores.

Comment: @Holger I think so before and even mention that in my post until I see this post, https://stackoverflow.com/a/22269778/5053214

Comment: Well, that’s an undocumented side effect without official support. And it only works for Fork/Join pools, not for arbitrary `Executor` implementations.