# Limit groupBy in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, grouping, java-stream, collectors

How can I limit groupBy by each entry?

For example (based on this example: [stream groupBy](http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/examples/java-util-stream-groupingBy-example/)):

```
studentClasses.add(new StudentClass("Kumar", 101, "Intro to Web"));
studentClasses.add(new StudentClass("White", 102, "Advanced Java"));
studentClasses.add(new StudentClass("Kumar", 101, "Intro to Cobol"));
studentClasses.add(new StudentClass("White", 101, "Intro to Web"));
studentClasses.add(new StudentClass("White", 102, "Advanced Web"));
studentClasses.add(new StudentClass("Sargent", 106, "Advanced Web"));
studentClasses.add(new StudentClass("Sargent", 103, "Advanced Web"));
studentClasses.add(new StudentClass("Sargent", 104, "Advanced Web"));
studentClasses.add(new StudentClass("Sargent", 105, "Advanced Web"));
```

This method return simple group:

```
   Map<String, List<StudentClass>> groupByTeachers = studentClasses
            .stream().collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(StudentClass::getTeacher));
```

What if I want to limit the returned collections?
Let's assume I want only the first N classes for every teacher. How can it be done?

Comment: What do you mean by first?, Do you means the classes with the lowest class number, the lowest names ASCIIBetically, or any random selection of N classes.  Note: the set of classes may be unordered.

Comment: @PeterLawrey You are right, I didn't mention that, for me the order is irrelevant but if we want a more thorough and general solution - ill be happy if you add a sorting example (by one of the fields)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It would be possible to introduce a new collector that limits the number of elements in the resulting list.

This collector will retain the head elements of the list ([in encounter order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29709140/1743880)). The accumulator and combiner throw away every elements when the limit has been reached during collection. The combiner code is a little tricky but this has the advantage that no additional elements are added only to be thrown away later.

```
private static <T> Collector<T, ?, List<T>> limitingList(int limit) {
    return Collector.of(
                ArrayList::new, 
                (l, e) -> { if (l.size() < limit) l.add(e); }, 
                (l1, l2) -> {
                    l1.addAll(l2.subList(0, Math.min(l2.size(), Math.max(0, limit - l1.size()))));
                    return l1;
                }
           );
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
Map<String, List<StudentClass>> groupByTeachers = 
       studentClasses.stream()
                     .collect(groupingBy(
                          StudentClass::getTeacher,
                          limitingList(2)
                     ));
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use [collectingAndThen](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-) to define a finisher operation on the resulting list. This way you can limit, filter, sort, ... the lists:

```
int limit = 2;

Map<String, List<StudentClass>> groupByTeachers =
    studentClasses.stream()
                  .collect(
                       groupingBy(
                           StudentClass::getTeacher,
                           collectingAndThen(
                               toList(),
                               l -> l.stream().limit(limit).collect(toList()))));
```

Comment: This would still be filtering the values after they're already added to the map, but the best answer so far.

Comment: The idea of a finisher is nice but there's no need for an O(n) cost in the finisher.  You can do something like `list -> list.size() <= limit ? list : list.subList(0, limit))` instead.  But I still far prefer Tunaki's solution, which doesn't require sticking the extra elements in the list at all.

Answer (score 4):

For this you need to `.stream()` the result of your Map. You can do this by doing:

```
// Part that comes from your example
Map<String, List<StudentClass>> groupByTeachers = studentClasses
            .stream().collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(StudentClass::getTeacher));

// Create a new stream and limit the result
groupByTeachers =
    groupByTeachers.entrySet().stream()
        .limit(N) // The actual limit
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            e -> e.getKey(),
            e -> e.getValue()
        ));
```

This isn't a very optimal way to do it. But if you `.limit()` on the initial list, then the grouping results would be incorrect. This is the safest way to guarantee the limit.

**EDIT:**

As stated in the comments this limits the teacher, not the class per teacher. In that case you can do:

```
groupByTeachers =
        groupByTeachers.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                e -> e.getKey(),
                e -> e.getValue().stream().limit(N).collect(Collectors.toList()) // Limit the classes PER teacher
            ));
```

Comment: Not very optimal, I assume he meant doing the this in the initial grouping.

Comment: This limits the number of teachers returned, not the number of classes per teacher.

Comment: Using `Map.replaceAll` would be better in the post-processing step than doing a separate stream for each element.  But @Tunaki's answer is better anyway.

Answer (score 3):

This would give you the desired result, but it still categorizes all the elements of the stream:

```
final int N = 10;
final HashMap<String, List<StudentClass>> groupByTeachers = 
        studentClasses.stream().collect(
            groupingBy(StudentClass::getTeacher, HashMap::new,
                collectingAndThen(toList(), list -> list.subList(0, Math.min(list.size(), N)))));
```