# Different result when using stream and parallelStream for the reduction of the same array of data?

Tags: java, java-8

I used reduce with stream and parallelStream on the same array with same lambda expression, and I expected the same result but the output is different. However, the results are different and I don't know why.

The code:

```
    System.out.println("Reduce me...");
    Integer[] arrx = {1,2,3,4};
    //        Reducing the Array

    Arrays
            .stream(arrx)
            .reduce((s1, s2) -> (int)Math.pow(s1,2) + (int)Math.pow(s2,2))
            .ifPresent(System.out::println);

    Arrays.asList(arrx)
            .parallelStream()
            .reduce((s1, s2) -> (int)Math.pow(s1,2) + (int)Math.pow(s2,2))
            .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

The output:

```
1172
650
```

Comment: Have you researched what the differences are betweet ``stream`` and ``parallelStream``? If you already know that this responsible for the different results...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why parallel stream get collected sequentially in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29709140/why-parallel-stream-get-collected-sequentially-in-java-8)

Comment: @Gatusko It may not be an exact duplicate, but there’s certainly a lot to be learned from that question. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `reduce` operation is depend on the encounter order of the array elements.

The `parallelStream` ignore that order and you received the different value each time you invoke the parallel execution.

Comment: Cool, I got it! Thanks

Comment: The parallel stream does *not* ignore the order. It assumes that you are passing an [*associative* function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Associativity) to reduce, as [mandated by the specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-). If you obey the contract, you will get correct results. For example `String::concat` depends on the order of the elements, but is an associative function that works flawlessly with parallel `reduce`.

Answer (score 2):

The sequential stream is deterministic, meaning we know which sequence of operations it performs:

```
1^2 + 2^2 = 1 + 4 = 5
5^5 + 3^2 = 25 + 9 = 34
34^2 + 4^2 = 1156 + 16 = 1172
```

The parallel stream may reduce elements in any order. The 650 you observed may have come about through these operations:

```
1^2 + 2^2 = 5
3^2 + 4^2 = 9 + 16 = 25
5^2 + 25^2 = 25 + 625 = 650
```

Next time you may get a different order and therefore a different result.